# Finding a closed timelike curve for a specific metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, causality

I am tasked with finding a timelike curve in a specific metric that supports it. How can I approach this problem? Metric is $$ds^2=-dt^2+a(r) dr^2+ b(r) d\varphi^2 + c(r) dtd\varphi,$$ where $a(r)=(1+r^2)^{-1}$, $b(r)=r^2(1-r^2)$ and $c(r)=2\sqrt{2} r^2$.

Comment: I don't think there's a general procedure. What's the metric?

Comment: Metric is $ds^2=-dt^2+a(r) dr^2+ b(r) d\varphi^2 + c(r) dtd\varphi$, where $a(r)=(1+r^2)^{-1}$, $b(r)=r^2(1-r^2)$ and $c(r)=2\sqrt{2} r^2$. @Javier